# jQuery remove() and appendTo() convert to javascript

Tags: javascript, append

I'm converting all my jQuery code to plain javascript. I'm struggling with one line of code:

```
$('.element-1').remove().appendTo('.element-2');
```

I'm not really sure what are the equivalent in JS for `remove()` and `appendTo()` and how to use them.

Thank you.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browser APIs don't give elements methods to *put* them somewhere, only to take other things inside themselves. So you need to reverse things and tell 2 to [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append) 1.

Elements can't exist in multiple parts of the DOM at once, so there's no need to explicitly remove an element.

```js
setTimeout(() => {

  document.querySelector('.element-2').append(
    document.querySelector('.element-1')
  );

}, 1500);
```

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
  border: solid red 1px;
}
```

```html
<span class="element-1">1</span>
<span class="element-2">2</span>
```

Comment: Thank you @Quentin. I just tried the code and I've got the following error: TypeError: undefined is not an object.

Comment: @MathieuPréaud — There is a live demo of the code working in my answer. I can't see what you've done differently in your attempt that would break it.

Comment: I'm sorry I forget to mention that I use Ajax for page transitioning on my site. So when I change page or I load a page that element-2 isn't on that page, I have the error mentioned above.

Comment: @MathieuPréaud — If your problem is caused by some Ajax side effects, then they should affect the code you provided in the original question, and whatever you did to time that code to run should work for this code.

Comment: @Yogi — It sounds like a sufficiently different problem that it should be a new question, not a rewrite of this one.

Comment: @Quentin – I mark your answer as the solution, because what you explained is part of the answer. I will open a new question with the Ajax side effect. Thank you.

Comment: @Quentin – Here is the new question if you feel like you want to have a look : )

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75755090/issue-to-load-script-tag-with-ajax-page-transition

Answer (score 0):

This is the code with pure JavaScript

```
let p = document.querySelector(".p");
let div = document.querySelector(".div");
let node = p.parentNode;
let clone = p.cloneNode(true);
node.removeChild(p);
div.appendChild(clone);
```

If you want to represent this like jQuery, load this code without jQuery library in your program.

```
function $(e){
  let el = document.querySelector(e);

     let remov =   function remove() {
          let node = el.parentNode;
       node.removeChild(el);
              return this;

        }; 
let appendT = function appendTo(r){
              let secondelem = document.querySelector(r);
              let clone = el.cloneNode(true);
        
              secondelem.appendChild(clone);
              return this;
        
  };
  
  return {remove:remov,appendTo:appendT};
}
$(".p").remove().appendTo(".div")
```

Do not add or link jQuery library or file in your program to know if it worked.
Please vote-up so I should know if it work.
I hope this help you.